# How to Scrape Bestbuy for Customer product reviews using Python?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I have been trying to scrape customer product reviews from Bestbuy for laptop products to analyze feedbacks but was unable to scrape it out. Any help here would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: learn beautifulsoup (bs4)

Answer (score 0):

If BestBuy is anything like EBay, they may have their front end code highly obfuscated. If this is the case it may be easier to use a headless selenium driver to extract reviews.